# Combobox with button instead of textbox

Tags: winforms, image, button, combobox

I would like to create a `combobox` without any `textbox` and with a customizable icon in the button that opens the `combobox`. Something like this image (forget about the `checkbox`s)

[image: Checkbox without textbox and customizable icon]

I don't need you to post the solution, just some directions or resources so I can know how to begin this customization.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContextMenuStrip which you manually display in the button's Click handler.

Comment: This would definitely be an option. I would prefer the combobox option but this can very well be my plan B. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't used the ContextmenuStrip but I took the button's idea and it really got a lot easier than change the combobox behaviour. Thanks!